# Facebook Webhooks API - How to get campaign from leadgen_id?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, webhooks

I'm using Facebooks Webhooks for lead generations. I successfully can fetch leadgen_id from the Facebooks callback.

So this is what Facebook returns for the leadgen field:

```
Array
(
    [entry] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [changes] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [field] => leadgen
                                    [value] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ad_id] => 0
                                            [form_id] => 1109138149146076
                                            [leadgen_id] => 1109157429144148
                                            [created_time] => 1467887375
                                            [page_id] => 152161181508654
                                            [adgroup_id] => 0
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [id] => 152161181508654
                    [time] => 1467887376
                )

        )

    [object] => page
)
```

Is it possible to somehow get campaign ID from these values that Facebook returns?

There is no clue to campaign in leadgen itself and in the form that I fetched with leadgen_id and form_id.

I also tried to fetch all ad account campaigns with

```
/v2.6/<ad_account_id>/campaigns
```

endpoint and thought that I will see some connection there with form or leadgen, but nothing there as well.

So, I need to fetch it so that I can group leadgen forms in Facebook. With current implementation, unfortunately it is not possible - I guess Facebook didn't thought of that :(

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone will struggle with this as well:

We can grab ad id info from:

```
'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/<AD_ID>?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>&fields=campaign_id';
```

And this will return us campaign id.

Reason why I didn't try this in first place, was because in initial response, Facebook returned ad_id as 0, but after some while I realised that this is probably because it was a test lead from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lead-ads-testing